# How to find place name inside a sentence using NLP and Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a sentence:

```
firstSentence = "Gnaeus Cornelius Scipio Hispanus expels all Jews from the city of Rome."
```

And I want to find the name of the place ("Rome").

I tried using geography:

```
from geograpy import extraction

e = extraction.Extractor(text=firstSentence)

e.find_entities()
print (e.places())
```

But I'm receiving error of:

```
    raise NotImplementedError("Use label() to access a node label.")
NotImplementedError: Use label() to access a node label.
```

I've also tried this:

```
import nltk
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(firstSentence))
entities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
print entities
```

But receiving:

```
(S
139/CD
  (ORGANIZATION
    BCE/NNP
    Gnaeus/NNP
    Cornelius/NNP
    Scipio/NNP
    Hispanus/NNP)
  expels/VBZ
  all/DT
  Jews/NNS
  from/IN
  the/DT
  city/NN
  of/IN
  (GPE Rome/NNP)
  ./.)
```

All of my places are going to be Cities or Countries.

I just need simple NLP functionality of finding place within a sentence. I don't mind using any other solution as long it is succeed. How can I do it?

Comment: What is `secondData`?

Comment: It is 'firstSentence'

Comment: I'm not very familiar with nltk, but a quick google searched revealed that "GPE Rome" refers to a geo-political entity. That could be a good place to start

Comment: This is the best I could come up with:
    for entity in entities:
        # print entity
        try:
            label = ""
            label = entity.label()
        except Exception as ex:
            pass
        if (label=='GPE'):
            place = entity[0][0]
            sentencePlacesArr.append(place)

I'm receiving output of 'Rome', but also ['Zeus', 'Jerusalem', 'Hanukkah'] in another sentence. I want ONLY cities and countries

Comment: I found this: 
from geotext import GeoText
places = GeoText("London is a great city")
places.cities

Answer (score 2):

```
from geotext import GeoText
sentence = " Tokyo is city in Japan "
places = GeoText(sentence)
print places.countries
print places.cities
```

Comment: why when I try "Flight Paris Boston" I get only `['Boston']` as a result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from geotext import GeoText
sentence = " Tokyo is city in Japan "
places = GeoText(sentence)
print places.countries
print places.cities
```

This is working fine, except that there should be any prepositions before and after the place's names.
"Flight Paris Boston" if replaced with flights for Paris and Boston works.