# NTLK - Classifying Noun as a Location

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use the NTLK to classify a noun as being a location. I realize this might be done with Named Entity Recognition, but that seems to apply to proper nouns in the context of a block of text. Is there a dataset I can check a noun against to see if it refers to a person, place, or thing? For example, I would like similar to 'facility', 'building',  and 'town' to be classified as a location (alternatively as a thing).

Comment: It might be possible to solve this problem using GeoText. Here is [one possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49555433/975097) that I found.